# Responsive page height as a div expands html css

Tags: html, css

**My situation:** 
On my page I have multiple collapsible panels in the right hand column of my main content.
At the moment what happens is when I expand the panel (which contains a large amount of text) it goes off the page. 
Therefore meaning that the user can't read it. This due the fact that the height is hard coded. 
Now what I want to happen is when the div expands, if it reaches the max height of the page, the page height expands to incorporate all of the text.

**Question:**
Is there a way to make it possible that the page height expands along with the div?

My CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:White;
    height: 0px auto;
}
#page {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 900px;
    padding: 0px 50px 50px 50px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#content {
    float: right;
    width: 580px;
}
```

Thankyou for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can make .container a clearfix so it will expand to the size of the floated element inside of it. Here's [a great article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) on using clearfix.

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:White;
    height: 0px auto;
}

.container:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
 }
```

That code will work for everything outside of IE6&7. If you need tose too just take a look at the article.

Comment: Hi, no sorry that code does not work...when i run it the page is just blank, possibly due to the hidden property?

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, try it again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using height you could try to set position to "absolute" and 0px top and bot on the .container?

```
.container {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:White;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys, I solved it....It was due to the fact that i was positioning the div with a relative height and width, so i just used margin-top instead.

Thanks to everyone